# How to show my datepicker and image from datagridview to datepickerbox and picturebox

Tags: c#

This is the code I am facing problem .. in fetching `uyearofjoin(datapicker)` and picture from picturebox how to write code for it

```
uname.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
ufather.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
umother.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
usurname.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
uphone.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
uemail.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
ugrno.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
ucourse.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
urollno.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
uyearofjoin.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to display `datetime` and `Image` from `dataGridView` columns in a `DateTimePicker` and `PictureBox` controls respectively.

Let's assume that `datetime` is available in `column 10` of `DataGridView` and `Image` is in `column 11`. The code to populate default value in `DateTimePicker` will be:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Value.ToString());
```

Code to display image in PictureBox will be:

```
//Get the blob data in a variable
var data = (Byte[])(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value);
//Create MemoryStream using blob data of image
var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
//Set the stream data to PictureBox
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);

// e.RowIndex => selected row for which data is displayed in control
```

Comment: friends how to show image in proper size in stretch format it is showing zoom image ... u r code is working properly ...;)

Comment: @FriendyTut  That's good. Then you should accept answer. You can check `SizeMode` property of `PictureBox` and set it `Auto`. Your next question has been posted as `Answer` for this question. Please delete that otherwise people will down vote on that. You can post it as new question if my suggestion don't work.

Answer (score 0):

friends how to show image in proper size in stretch                                                 ..
            ..//Get the blob data in a variable
            var data = (Byte[])(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value);
            //Create MemoryStream using blob data of image
            var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            //Set the stream data to PictureBox
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                                                                                                                             ...image is not showing in proper size it is showing zoom how to resolve this error ....the code is perfect and working only this issuse i want image in proper format size like stretch

Answer (score 0):

can anyone tell me the datepicker value from datagridview  is not showing in my datepicker

showing only the default date value (8/10/2013)

and even when updating the datepicker the value is shown in my 
datagridvierw (example 10/12/2015) updated  but onclick of mouseclick event the value is not showing instead of updated date it is showing the default date value

```
(8/10/2013)
```

again 
not showing updated one